# Empty event value in AWS Lambda called from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently building all my javascript front-end code to put it on AWS in NodeJS.
My request chain will be the following :

- The user calls the NodeJS AWS-hosted function from the Javascript with the following call (1)
- The NodeJS function calls a python script used to get a file size. When invoked locally, this function works well. But here the `event` value received is empty, so nothing can happen... (2) (3)
- The size is updated and available in my DynamoDB Table.

Does someone have an idea on why the event passed in empty ? Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

**CodeBlock 1 :**

```
API.post("notes", "/upload", {
    test: {
      "userId": toto['userId'],
      "noteId": toto['noteId']
    }
  });
```

**CodeBlock 2 :**

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";

export function main(event, context, callback) {
  var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
     region: 'us-east-1'
  });

  lambda.invoke({
     FunctionName: 'miseajour',
     InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
     Payload: event.test
     }, function(error, data) {
         if (error) {
             callback(null, failure({error: error}));
         } else if(data){
             callback(null, success(data));
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: A bit more context would help. Are you using a library for the API, e.g. AWS Amplify?

Answer (score 0):

The `invoke` function of the AWS JavaScript SDK expects a Buffer, a Typed Array, a Blob, or a String, on the `Payload` attribute. You can check it out on the SDK [documentation site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property). Here is the entire interface of the `invoke` method, taken from that link:

```
var params = {
  FunctionName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ClientContext: 'STRING_VALUE',
  InvocationType: Event | RequestResponse | DryRun,
  LogType: None | Tail,
  Payload: Buffer.from('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' /* Strings will be Base-64 encoded on your behalf */,
  Qualifier: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

In your case, you are passing an object. Try converting it into a `string` first using `JSON.stringify`.